# error while installing the libmemcached

Tags: linux, centos, memcached, memcache

I get this while installing libmemcached

```
root@server [/libmemcached]# make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/libmemcached'
if /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CXX --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.  -I. -I. -ggdb   -DBUILDING_HASHKIT  -MT libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo -MD -MP -MF "libhashkit/.deps/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.Tpo" -c -o libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo `test -f 'libhashkit/aes.cc' || echo './'`libhashkit/aes.cc; \
        then mv -f "libhashkit/.deps/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.Tpo" "libhashkit/.deps/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.Plo"; else rm -f "libhashkit/.deps/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
./libtool: line 866: X--tag=CXX: command not found
./libtool: line 899: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
./libtool: line 866: X--mode=compile: command not found
./libtool: line 1032: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
./libtool: line 1033: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: Xg++: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-DHAVE_CONFIG_H: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-ggdb: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-DBUILDING_HASHKIT: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-MT: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: Xlibhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo: No such file or directory
./libtool: line 1176: X-MD: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-MP: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: X-MF: command not found
./libtool: line 1176: Xlibhashkit/.deps/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.Tpo: No such file or directory
./libtool: line 1176: X-c: command not found
./libtool: line 1228: Xlibhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo: No such file or directory
./libtool: line 1233: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make[1]: *** [libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/libmemcached'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

OUTPUT OF ./configure

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for isainfo... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether __SUNPRO_C is declared... no
checking whether __ICC is declared... no
checking "C Compiler version--yes"... "gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)"
checking "C++ Compiler version"... "g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)"
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for size_t... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for library containing clock_gettime... -lrt
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking size of off_t... 8
checking size of size_t... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking if time_t is unsigned... no
checking for setsockopt... yes
checking for bind... yes
checking whether the compiler provides atomic builtins... yes
checking assert.h usability... yes
checking assert.h presence... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking whether to enable assertions... yes
checking whether it is safe to use -fdiagnostics-show-option... yes
checking whether it is safe to use -floop-parallelize-all... no
checking whether it is safe to use -Wextra... yes
checking whether it is safe to use -Wformat... yes
checking whether it is safe to use -Wconversion... no
checking whether it is safe to use -Wmissing-declarations from C++... no
checking whether it is safe to use -Wframe-larger-than... no
checking whether it is safe to use -Wlogical-op... no
checking whether it is safe to use -Wredundant-decls from C++... yes
checking whether it is safe to use -Wattributes from C++... no
checking whether it is safe to use -Wno-attributes... no
checking for perl... perl
checking for dpkg-gensymbols... no
checking for lcov... no
checking for genhtml... no
checking for sphinx-build... no
checking for working -pipe... yes
checking for bison... bison
checking for flex... flex
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 98304
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether the -Werror option is usable... yes
checking for simple visibility declarations... yes
checking for ISO C++ 98 include files... 
checking whether memcached executable path has been provided... no
checking for memcached... /usr/local/bin/memcached
checking whether memcached_sasl executable path has been provided... no
checking for memcached_sasl... no
checking whether gearmand executable path has been provided... no
checking for gearmand... no
checking libgearman/gearmand.h usability... no
checking libgearman/gearmand.h presence... no
checking for libgearman/gearmand.h... no
checking for library containing getopt_long... none required
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking the location of cstdint... configure: WARNING: Could not find a cstdint header.
<stdint.h>
checking the location of cinttypes... configure: WARNING: Could not find a cinttypes header.
<inttypes.h>
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for htonll... no
checking for working SO_SNDTIMEO... yes
checking for working SO_RCVTIMEO... yes
checking for supported struct padding... yes
checking for alarm... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for getline... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for memchr... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for pipe2... no
checking for select... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for sqrt... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for strtoull... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking cxxabi.h usability... yes
checking cxxabi.h presence... yes
checking for cxxabi.h... yes
checking sys/sysctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking umem.h usability... no
checking umem.h presence... no
checking for umem.h... no
checking for C++ compiler vendor... gnu
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for error_at_line... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking whether strerror_r is declared... yes
checking for strerror_r... yes
checking whether strerror_r returns char *... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... no
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... (cached) yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... (cached) no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking whether the compiler supports GCC C++ ABI name demangling... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h usability... no
checking sasl/sasl.h presence... no
checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
checking uuid/uuid.h usability... yes
checking uuid/uuid.h presence... yes
checking for uuid/uuid.h... yes
checking for main in -luuid... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for floor in -lm... yes
checking for sigignore... yes
checking atomic.h usability... no
checking atomic.h presence... no
checking for atomic.h... no
checking for setppriv... no
checking for winsock2.h... no
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for fnmatch.h... yes
checking for MSG_NOSIGNAL... yes
checking for MSG_DONTWAIT... yes
checking for MSG_MORE... yes
checking event.h usability... yes
checking event.h presence... yes
checking for event.h... yes
checking for main in -levent... yes
checking for endianness... little
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating docs/conf.py
config.status: creating libhashkit-1.0/configure.h
config.status: creating libmemcached-1.0/configure.h
config.status: creating libmemcached-1.2/configure.h
config.status: creating libmemcached-2.0/configure.h
config.status: creating support/libmemcached.pc
config.status: creating support/libmemcached.spec
config.status: creating support/libmemcached-fc.spec
config.status: creating libtest/version.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
---
Configuration summary for libmemcached version 1.0.6

   * Installation prefix:       /usr/local
   * System type:               unknown-linux-gnu
   * Host CPU:                  x86_64
   * C Compiler:                gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
   * Assertions enabled:        yes
   * Debug enabled:             no
   * Warnings as failure:       no
   * SASL support:              

---
```

anyone knows how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you run configure script first (`./configure`)? As an aside advice, try to avoid building as root whenever applicable.

Comment: yes i did run it

Comment: Any error/warning while running the configure script? The output is saved in `config.log` file.

Comment: I edited my question and added ./configure output

Comment: What platform is this? Compiler version? You are missing a few required headers. Cheers, -Brian

Comment: Strange...how did all those X's get added?

Comment: @Brian linux centos, how to solve it any idea ?

Comment: @MarkWagner no idea :S

Comment: When I try to compile libmemcached version 1.0.6 on a Centos 5 server the output is nothing like that. The output of ./configure is similar.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this error caused by the older version of `libtool`:

```
# rpm -qi libtool
```

Remove the binary (`yum remove libtool`), download the [latest version](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/), compile with `--prefix=/usr` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your C compiler. See [here](http://www.bxtra.net/articles/2011-03-22/how-to-install-memcached-on-centos-memcached-pecl-update-20110322)

> GCC version is too old